# How to combine different graphs and plot it in only one graph?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

My data is include number of cars in each day and each minutes per day. I know how to plot the data only for one sepecific day in August for example. However, I do not know how to plot other month and bring all of them in only one graph.

Can anyone help me?

[Here is a small sample of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJvLn.png)

[Final Photo: it is what I have achieved, but do not know how to add legend for them and how to change the color or change the shape of graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frjI7.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your relevant code.

Comment: If the current answer is insufficient, please edit the code into your question, and with more context than that image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) method if you're using pyplot.

Comment: Can you? If you have 1 value per day that's good, but does it support hours too?

Comment: First two arguments are numpy arrays. You should just feed it x and y values, and you can supply a label to indicate month.

Comment: Yes it also support hours. Please see the photoes for better understanding. Thanks in advance for your help @Guimoute

Comment: Please see the photoes that I have uploaded. I know how to plot the data but I want to bring all month in only one graph not the separate graph. @Gloweye

Comment: I'm gonna need to see a lot more of your code to get there, @Alisha

Comment: Please see my Final Photo @Gloweye